# Traduction de « review » et « survey »

Tags: traduction, anglais, mathématiques

Je me soucie de la traduction des mots « review » et « survey ». En mathématiques, on rencontre souvent « review of a book » ou « a survey on recent developments ».

D'après vous, quels sont les bons mots pour traduire ces termes?

Comment: Je pense que la question aurait méritée d'être séparée en deux, une question pour chaque mot.

Comment: Merci. J'y ferais attention la prochaine fois.

Comment: Le mot "survey" en francais serait plutot "sondage". Et "review", tu pourrais te servir de "revue" d'apres le dictionnaire Francais-Anglais "Le Robert & Collins" edition senior.

Comment: merci. Mais je pense que le mot "survey" que j'aborde au-dessus est différent du mot "sondage". "Survey", à ma connaissance, est une collection d'informations utiles et récentes d'un problème de recherche quelconque. Tandis que sondage, à ma connaissance, est une collection d'avis d'autres personnes. 

Donc le "survey" en question est plus proche du mot "résumé", mais ce n'est pas identique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A *book review* est en général rendu, selon les cas (les endroits de parution ou les traditions) par :

- « **[compte rendu](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/compte%20rendu) de lecture** ».  C'est le mot en général  employé par les revues universitaires.
- « **[critique](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/critique)** » (B. 3. a.).  C'est en général le mot employé par la presse grand public.

La [Gazette des Mathématiciens](http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/Gazette/2013/138/) (Publication de la société Mathématique de France) appelle sa rubrique comptes rendus de livres tout simplement  « [Livres](http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/Gazette/2013/138/smf_gazette_138_97-99.pdf) ».

*Survey*  ça peut-être une **enquête**, une **étude de cas**, un **point sur** quelque chose (actualité immédiate peut-être plus large que *survey*), un **compendium** (mot très peu usité en dehors de la sphère universitaire).

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Après avoir lu votre réponse, je pense que j'utiliserai le mot "compte rendu" et "étude" pour ces termes.